# Send windows push notification to specific channel uri

Tags: javascript, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I'm attempting to send to a windows push notification to a specific client with a channel uri from the azure mobile service back end(javascript).  So far I found  [wns object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj860484.aspx), which only supports specific tags.Any api which supports sending push notification to specific device using channel uri?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the Notification Hubs SDK directly (bypassing the Azure Mobile Apps / Services SDK, which is only used for registration).  This allows you to use the REST endpoint to do a Direct Send: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608572.aspx

Comment: but does support channel uri paramater? .In fact I need to send a notification to specific device

Comment: When you register a device, the unique device ID is registered.  You will send to the unique device ID - this may be different than the channel URI.  The Direct Send API is the way to do it.